# Can't run gocv on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, opencv, go, aws-lambda

I tried to build a go script (with gocv package) from Windows 10 and I get this error

```
/home/denny/go/src/gocv.io/x/gocv/calib3d_string.go:3:9: undefined: CalibFlag
/home/denny/go/src/gocv.io/x/gocv/core_string.go:3:9: undefined: MatType
/home/denny/go/src/gocv.io/x/gocv/core_string.go:57:9: undefined: CompareType
/home/denny/go/src/gocv.io/x/gocv/core_string.go:75:9: undefined: CovarFlags
/home/denny/go/src/gocv.io/x/gocv/core_string.go:93:9: undefined: DftFlags
/home/denny/go/src/gocv.io/x/gocv/core_string.go:113:9: undefined: RotateFlag
/home/denny/go/src/gocv.io/x/gocv/core_string.go:125:9: undefined: KMeansFlags
/home/denny/go/src/gocv.io/x/gocv/core_string.go:137:9: undefined: NormType
/home/denny/go/src/gocv.io/x/gocv/core_string.go:159:9: undefined: TermCriteriaType
/home/denny/go/src/gocv.io/x/gocv/core_string.go:169:9: undefined: SolveDecompositionFlags
/home/denny/go/src/gocv.io/x/gocv/core_string.go:169:9: too many errors
```

this is the command I used

```
set GOOS=linux
set GOARCH=amd64
set CGO_ENABLED=0
go build -o main main.go
```

Then I tried to build it on Ubuntu with this command, which it succeed

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o main main.go
zip main.zip main
```

However, I get this error when I tried to run the zip on AWS Lambda

```
START RequestId: d9cd01bb-b7d6-47ed-9852-07a43f3b3ce1 Version: $LATEST
/var/task/main: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_highgui.so.4.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Have anyone tried to get gocv on AWS Lambda?

Comment: Your issue is also [discussed in the issues section of the project](https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv/issues/636), maybe someone there comes up with an solution. [Someone also said](https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv/issues/615#issuecomment-600318196) that cross-compiling with OpenCV and gocv is not feasible and the compilation should be done on the same operating system; I'm not sure if that's possible in this case

Comment: yeah i checked there, i'm having the same problem. I hope maybe someone here knows how to get it on lambda

Comment: try ``GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o main main.go``

Comment: I get this error `/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running g++ failed: exit status 1` when i tried that command. It leads me to [this issue](https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv/issues/601) and i can't resolve it as well..